# Parse Query Include method not including all data expected

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am doing a query onto a class where I have a pointer to a User.

I do `query.include('byUser')` and when I log out the query result it's shown but when I try to get a specific attribute like email. It doesnt exist.

I also first thought it was odd that I have to get the User details by doing:

```
const userDetails = query.get("byUser").attributes;
```

Do I have to do `.attributes`? And also why isn't the email showing up. Everything else seems to show up in the attributes section.

Thanks

Comment: verify the type of 'byUser' .. if it is a pointer to a class and u include it then the response will include the entire targetClass object < all props by default>

Comment: @RobertRowntree Yes I looked and it is indeed a pointer to User class.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to get the `byUser` email by doing `const username = results.get('byUser').email`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in parse, you can not query the email field of other users. you can see the email field only if you are the signed in user. This is a security mechanism.

A. If you want to get the email field for a user object, you can do two things:

1. Pass the user session token to the query.

`new Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(<userId>,{sessionToken:<userSessionToken>});`

2. Use master key. (Note: You have to set the master key before.)

`new Parse.Query(Parse.User).find({useMasterKey:true});`

B. Your include method is correct and it it will fetch the `byUser` object. You do not need to use .attributes.

**UPDATE:**
You can also set a `publicEmail` field in your User class which will not be filtered out by parse-server. to automate this, you can write a cloud code.

Cloud Code Example (on parse-server V 3.0.0 and above):

**PLEASE NOTE THAT YOU CAN NOT USE ASYNC FUNCTIONS FOR PARSE-SERVER < V 3.0.0**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, async req=>{
  if (!req.original && !req.master && req.object.get('email')){
    req.object.set('publicEmail',req.object.get('email'));
  }
})
```

Now, if new user sign up, this cloud code will automatically adds a new field to the user object `publicEmail` which is not filtered by parse-server.

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad to use master key on client side?

Comment: It is definitely a terrible idea to put your master key on the client side. however, parse-server does not allow you to access the email field out of the box and without using a master key. You can do another approach, which is setting a public email field on the user class. You can even automate this. I am going to update my reply to explain how you can do this.